# Server Ram Full when I Call PHP Api from mobile

Tags: php, android, mysqli, ram

For a android app I create apis to get data from server. But server ram become full when I run my app. I follow this steps...

connection:

```
include("connection.php");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Query:

```
$sql1="SELECT ..."; 
$result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);
```

Close Connection:

```
$mysqli->close();
```

One example of my queries:

```
 $sql1="SELECT user_id FROM user_table WHERE email like '$email'";  
 $result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);
 if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
   while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
     $user_id=$row["user_id"];
   }
}
```

Normally I select 20 to 50 rows from 100 to 200 rows.

Is there any problem of my code that can be responsible for ram overflow.

Thanks.

Comment: where do you actually process the selected data? that's the important part, because i guess you just try to process too many items at once without freeing any memory in the process. so - how do you process the data, and how many rows do you typically select?

Comment: You have to provide more informations, what's inside your table, how many rows are you retreving, what are you doing with the result ?

Comment: Thanks @FranzGleichmann & Gwendal.
I just add a Query.